# PCL library and concurrency

Tags: c++, windows-7, point-cloud-library

I have started working in a project using the PCL library under Windows 7. My question is if PCL provides any structures or algorithms for concurrent work. For example, creating a new point cloud from a data set concurrently; something like *pcl::io::loadPCDFileKCores*. 
I have searched around in the API documentation and Google but find nothing.

Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCL 1.7 does offer some facilities for exploting multiple processing cores on a system using GPU or CPU.

PCL uses multiple CPU cores on a system through the [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/) API. You can check for multiple core enabled classes by [searching PCL documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/search.php?query=openMP) for the "OpenMP" keyword (naive, but effective way!). As at the time of writing the reported OpenMP enabled classes are:

- pcl::RangeImage
- pcl::tracking::ParticleFilterOMPTracker
- pcl::FPFHEstimationOMP
- pcl::NormalEstimationOMP
- pcl::Narf
- pcl::tracking::KLDAdaptiveParticleFilterOMPTracker
- pcl::SHOTColorEstimationOMP
- pcl::SHOTEstimationOMP
- pcl::NormalEstimationOMP< PointInT, Eigen::MatrixXf >

If you search the PCL documentation for the [GPU](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/search.php?query=gpu) or CUDA keywords a similar, but much longer, list of GPU-enabled classes is reported.